# Facebook login, problem with hash key - Flutter , How to generate Facebook Hashkey in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, facebook, hash

**A window appears with the entrance to Facebook and when you click continue to arise an error**

> SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1349195 [message]: the key hash does not match
>   any of the saved hashes

```
login() async {
    final facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin();
    final result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);
    switch (result.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        print(result.accessToken.token);
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home_screen');
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        print('CANCELED BY USER');
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        print(result.errorMessage);
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have to update your app settings on developers.facebook.com with the right key hash

Comment: You need provide your development hash key in facebook developer panel.
Take a look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#release-key-hash)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1. Go to your output apk files (Usually `<project_root>\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk`).
2. Use keytools to get the SHA1 value (run in terminal / git bash):

   `keytool -printcert -jarfile app-debug.apk`
3. Convert the HEX value to base64 to get value that ends with =. (i.e. Use [this site](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/base64_encode.html). Be aware to have at `Input type` selected `Hex`. And delete all `:` between SHA1 key groups -> `AB:CD:EF` = wrong, but `ABCDEF` = correct)
4. Update that value to key hashes under your android platform.

Comment: this help me solve the flutter app facebook login problem.

Comment: Thanks it is solve my problem. And don't forget to choose hex category on this site link.

Comment: Do flutter use its own cert for app sigining?

Comment: for the release hash key, I just need to change the `app-debug.apk` to `app-release.apk` right?

Answer (score 11):

This is how I generated facebook keyhash for android build

1. Open android project in android studio
2. Open MainActivity which should be extending to `FlutterActivity`
3. Copy this code and paste in MainActivity

import android.content.Context

```
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Base64
import android.util.Log
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException


class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        printHashKey(this@MainActivity)
    }
    fun printHashKey(pContext: Context) {
        try {
            val info: PackageInfo = pContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pContext.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
            for (signature in info.signatures) {
                val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
                md.update(signature.toByteArray())
                val hashKey = String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0))
                Log.i("MainActivity", "printHashKey() Hash Key: $hashKey")
            }
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "printHashKey()", e)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "printHashKey()", e)
        }
    }
}
```

**Alernative Solution** :-

> Run this command in the terminal to generate debug key

How to generate Facebook hash key

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: why no one upvoted this answer till now. its the easiest thank you

Comment: agree with @evals

Comment: how can i get release key

Comment: just attach your device with system while android studio opened , so in the logs you would see the release key as well

Comment: MainActivity.kt: (22, 32): Unresolved reference: Context

Answer (score 5):

There are two kinds key hashes the release, debug to get
debug use this
for mac

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

for Windows

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

For release

```
keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

if something goes wrong re read all the instructions from developerfacebook good luck.

Comment: How about for Linux ??

Comment: You can use the mac code for that

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the hash key to your app page on facebook.

To get the hash key open the cmd end enter (download cygwin if you don't have it)

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\cygwin64\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\cygwin64\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

After that it will print the hash key just copy it and paste it in the developer.facebook app page

Answer (score 2):

After hours of trying I've finally found a solution.

1. Delete any app on the website of [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com)
2. Delete the file `debug.keystore` under `C:\Users\<username>\.android`
3. Generate a new key (by running your app again)
4. Create a new app on [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com) and add the new hash key
   Re-run your app

Success!

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this simple package for generating facebook keyhash. No need to write/copy/paste native code.

link: [flutter_facebook_keyhash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_keyhash)

Dart code:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    printKeyHash();
  }

  void printKeyHash() async{

   String? key=await FlutterFacebookKeyhash.getFaceBookKeyHash ??
          'Unknown platform version';
   print(key??"");

  }
```